# Comparing the foreign key of 1 table to the primary of another

Tags: python, django

As the title says I'm trying to compare the foreign key of one table to the primary of another if they match print out an editable version of the view and if they don't make it read-only.

Models:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True, auto_created=True)
    staffmember = models.ForeignKey('users.Users', verbose_name='Users',on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True,
                                    related_name='ticket')
    ticketId = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ticketName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ticketDescription = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    ticketTime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=Roles, default=developer)
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=Condition, default=Opened)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=priority, default=low)

class Users(AbstractUser):
    pass
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True, auto_created=True)
    username = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=25, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, unique=True)

    objects = Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

View

```
class EditTicketView(UpdateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
        model = Ticket
        template_name = 'editTicket.html'
        fields = ['ticketName', 'ticketDescription', 'condition', 'priority', 'role']
        success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
```

Form

```
class EditTicketForms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Ticket
        fields = ['ticketName', 'ticketDescription', 'condition', 'priority']
```

HTML

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Edit Ticket{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Package Details</h1>
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Add Comment">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm trying to compare the user ID with the foreign key in tickets called staffmember any help would be great.

Comment: One option would be to put the read-only logic in your template.  In the template, your request's user should be `{{ request.user }}` and your ticket's user should be `{{ object.staffmember }}`.  To compare them, you can use `==`.

Comment: i literally cannot thank you enough i spent hours on that for such a simple thing